# Fitting a Fine-Gray model with interaction in R (package RiskRegression - function FGR)

Tags: r, regression, survival-analysis

My dataset is very similar to the dataset 'Melanoma' included in the RiskRegression package : 3307 patients, 502 events of interest (fracture), 264 deaths (competing risk). The *time* is the years after bone examination (DXA) and *status* is coded in this way O=censored,1=fracture,2=death).
I am trying to fit a Fine-Gray model with interaction, but when I introduce an interaction term under the form of var1 * var2) I receive an error message :

« Error in design[pos, , drop = FALSE] : subscript out of bounds » .

Here is my code :

```
fgr<-FGR(Hist(time,status)~age+htot_bmd+tot_bmd+amof+PR+atcdtfam+AlcFR+PR+BMI3C+malchronFR+malchronFR*BMI3C+atcdtfam*PR,data=df2,cause=1)
```

I tried the code provided in the paper of Zhongheng et al. "Model validation for competing risks data" with the data set 'Melanoma' introducing an interaction but the same error message appears.

Is it possible to introduce an interaction with FGR and how to do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do with your data with the following code:

```
> library(riskRegression)
> library(survival)
> library(prodlim)
> library(cmprsk)
> library(readxl)
> df2 <- read_xlsx("/Users/zhang/Downloads/df2.xlsx") 
New names:                                                                                      
* `` -> ...1
> df2
# A tibble: 300 x 14
   ...1  neck_bmd htot_bmd tot_bmd   age AlcFR    PR atcdtfam malchronFR  amof BMI3C  time event
   <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
 1 1        0.960    0.953   1.04   79.1     0     0        0          0     2     3  9.00 Cen  
 2 2        0.612    0.620   0.988  79.2     0     0        0          0     0     3  4.76 MOF  
 3 3        0.880    0.990   0.827  78.6     0     0        0          1     1     2  9.14 Cen  
 4 4        0.869    0.905   0.866  79.0     0     0        0          0     0     2  9.11 Cen  
 5 5        0.863    0.991   1.17   79.0     1     0        1          0     0     2 10.2  Cen  
 6 6        0.722    0.902   0.842  78.8     0     0        0          0     0     2  9.09 Cen  
 7 7        0.853    0.929   1.33   76.9     0     0        0          0     0     3 10.1  Cen  
 8 8        0.830    0.912   0.947  77.0     0     0        0          1     0     2  8.13 Cen  
 9 9        0.872    0.968   1.22   77.2     1     0        0          0     0     2  8.12 Cen  
10 10       0.639    0.776   0.822  76.7     0     0        0          1     0     2  8.12 Cen  
# … with 290 more rows, and 1 more variable: status <dbl>
> modMatrix <- model.matrix(~age+htot_bmd+tot_bmd+amof+atcdtfam+
+                             AlcFR+PR+BMI3C*malchronFR+neck_bmd,df2)[,-1] 
> dtInteraction <- cbind(data.frame( modMatrix),
+                        status=df2$status, time=df2$time) 
> fgr.Interaction<- FGR(as.formula(paste("Hist(time,status)~",
+                                        paste(names(dtInteraction[1:11]),collapse = "+"))),
+                       data = dtInteraction,cause = 1)
> score.cv<-riskRegression::Score(list("Fine-Gray"= fgr.Interaction),
+                                 formula = Hist(time,status)~1,
+                                 data=dtInteraction,times = sort(unique(dtInteraction$time))[25:200],
+                                 cens.method="jackknife",
+                                 se.fit=1L,plots="calibration")
> plotCalibration(score.cv,times = df2$time[11],
+                 cens.method="local")
```

[image]

Comment: I passed the code on another selection of my data (n=500) and I got a graph but if I try with more cases, I receive a message like "Requested time 10.1163586584531 is not in object". How to be sure that the requested time is present ?. I don't really understand the [25:200] in the code "sort(unique(dtInteraction$time))[25:200]" . Thanks alot.

Comment: Don’t use some extreme time points, I use the rank 25to 200 is arbitrary but to make sure the range is not too extreme

Answer (score 1):

You can use a model.matrix function as follows. The crr()function can do the interaction.

```
> library(riskRegression)
> library(survival)
> library(prodlim)
> library(cmprsk)
> data(Melanoma)
> Melanoma$id<-1:nrow(Melanoma)
> set.seed(123)
> ind.split<-sample(1:nrow(Melanoma),
+                     round(nrow(Melanoma)*4/5),
+                     replace = F)
> dftrain<-Melanoma[ind.split,]
> dftest<-Melanoma[-ind.split,]
> fgr.full<-FGR(Hist(time,status)~age+thick+ici+
+                 epicel+ulcer+sex+invasion,
+               data=dftrain,cause=1)
> modMatrix <- model.matrix(~thick+ici+
+                             epicel+ulcer*age+invasion,dftrain)[,-1]
> 
> fgrMod <- crr(ftime = dftrain$time,
+               fstatus = dftrain$status,
+               cov1 = modMatrix,failcode=2)
> summary(fgrMod)
Competing Risks Regression

Call:
crr(ftime = dftrain$time, fstatus = dftrain$status, cov1 = modMatrix, 
    failcode = 2)

                    coef exp(coef) se(coef)      z p-value
thick             0.1194     1.127   0.1292  0.924  0.3600
ici1             -0.7607     0.467   1.0721 -0.710  0.4800
ici2             -0.8531     0.426   0.9379 -0.910  0.3600
ici3             -0.1924     0.825   1.0895 -0.177  0.8600
epicelpresent     0.8973     2.453   0.8434  1.064  0.2900
ulcerpresent     -0.7101     0.492   1.9776 -0.359  0.7200
age               0.0627     1.065   0.0227  2.766  0.0057
invasionlevel.1  -1.2031     0.300   0.7068 -1.702  0.0890
invasionlevel.2  -2.0365     0.130   1.4121 -1.442  0.1500
ulcerpresent:age  0.0152     1.015   0.0320  0.473  0.6400

                 exp(coef) exp(-coef)    2.5% 97.5%
thick                1.127      0.887 0.87475  1.45
ici1                 0.467      2.140 0.05716  3.82
ici2                 0.426      2.347 0.06780  2.68
ici3                 0.825      1.212 0.09752  6.98
epicelpresent        2.453      0.408 0.46968 12.81
ulcerpresent         0.492      2.034 0.01019 23.71
age                  1.065      0.939 1.01844  1.11
invasionlevel.1      0.300      3.330 0.07515  1.20
invasionlevel.2      0.130      7.664 0.00819  2.08
ulcerpresent:age     1.015      0.985 0.95348  1.08

Num. cases = 164
Pseudo Log-likelihood = -52.3 
Pseudo likelihood ratio test = 21.1  on 10 df,
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But when I try to run the code for the calibration "score<-Score(list("Cause-specific Cox"=csc,"Fine-Gray"=fgr,"Full"=fgrMod),formula = Hist(time,status)~1,data=df2,times=seq(2,6,1),plots = "calibration",summary = "risk")" I get the error message "Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...)". In fact I wanted to produce figure 3,5 and 6 of your paper . Sorry not to have been more clear in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Then you can try the following code:

```
library(riskRegression)
library(survival)
 library(prodlim)
 library(cmprsk)
data(Melanoma)
 Melanoma$id<-1:nrow(Melanoma)
 set.seed(123)
 ind.split<-sample(1:nrow(Melanoma),
                                         round(nrow(Melanoma)*4/5),
                                        replace = F)
 dftrain<-Melanoma[ind.split,]
 dftest<-Melanoma[-ind.split,]
 fgr.NoInteraction<-FGR(Hist(time,status)~age+thick+ici+
                                   epicel+ulcer+sex+invasion,
                               data=dftrain,cause=1)
 modMatrix <- model.matrix(~thick+ici+
                            epicel+ulcer*age+invasion,dftrain)[,-1]
 
dtInteraction <- cbind(data.frame( modMatrix),status=dftrain$status,
                       time=dftrain$time)
fgr.Interaction<- FGR(as.formula(paste("Hist(time,status)~",paste(names(dtInteraction[1:9]),collapse = "+"))),
           data = dtInteraction,cause = 1)
score.cv<-riskRegression::Score(list("Fine-Gray"= fgr.Interaction),
                formula = Hist(time,status)~1,
                data=dtInteraction,times = sort(unique(dtInteraction$time)),
                cens.method="jackknife",
                se.fit=1L,plots="calibration")
plotCalibration(score.cv,times = 3330,cens.method="local")
```

We still need to add interaction term with model.matrix. However, we can only use object from FGR as input  to the Score function. The other figures in [the paper](http://atm.amegroups.com/article/view/21020/pdf) can be done with similar tricks.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I adapted the code for my data but I received this error message "Warning messages:
1: In matrix(risk[Cases], nrow = nbCases, ncol = nbControls1) :
  data length exceeds size of matrix
2: In matrix(ipcwCases[Cases], nrow = nbCases, ncol = nbControls1) :
  data length exceeds size of matrix"
>Here is my adapted code in the next comment

Comment: "modMatrix <- model.matrix(~age+htot_bmd+tot_bmd+amof+PR*atcdtfam+AlcFR+PR+BMI3C*malchronFR+neck_bmd,df2)[,-1]
dtInteraction <- cbind(data.frame( modMatrix),status=df2$status,
                       time=df2$time)
fgr.Interaction<- FGR(as.formula(paste("Hist(time,status)~",paste(names(dtInteraction[1:12]),collapse = "+"))),     the rest of the code in the next comment

Comment: data = dtInteraction,cause = 1)
score.cv<-riskRegression::Score(list("Fine-Gray"= fgr.Interaction),
                formula = Hist(time,status)~1,
                data=dtInteraction,times = sort(unique(dtInteraction$time)),
                cens.method="jackknife",
                se.fit=1L,plots="calibration")" " Could you help me again ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: This maybe due to the special case in your dataset; can you simulate a small example to replicate the error message so that I can figure out what’s wrong with the code